# How useful are "modman" Technology in Magento2?

Tags: magento-2.0, modman

How useful are "modman" Technology in Magento2?

Anyone have an idea about modman?

Compare with another like as Github/bitbucket.

Comment: Provide more detail with links

Comment: https://webtise.com/an-introduction-to-modman-for-magento/

Comment: Have u tried steps mentioned? Where u stuck?

Comment: How to useful technology..give me an example to compare other Git/bitbucket or etc.

Comment: Modman has nothing to do with where your Git repository is hosted

Answer (score 3):

It can be useful for making it much easier to use version control while developing modules.

Max Pronko has written up a development workflow using modman: https://www.maxpronko.com/blog/magento-2-module-in-a-separate-repository